# How does one find new spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I am creating a Warlock with the pact of the tome and reading the Book of Ancient Secrets invocation I got a little lost. It says:

> On your adventures, you can add other ritual spells to your Book of Shadows. When you find such a spell, you can add it to the book if the spell’s level is equal to or less than half your warlock level (rounded up) and if you can spare the time to transcribe the spell. For each level of the spell, the transcription process takes 2 hours and costs 50 gp for the rare inks needed to inscribe it.

I am new to D&D so the concept of finding a new spell isn't very clear to me. Can someone please explain how could I learn new rituals with my warlock?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You find them as treasure!

Everyone likes gold and magical treasures, but a warlock or wizard prizes the treasure of knowledge above all. Ancient tomes of incantations, a scrap of lost research, a scroll encoding a single forgotten magical effect, a spell carved in ten-foot-high letters into solid rock in the fabled city of the Magus Confederation—these are treasure worth more than gold, because *lost* bits of knowledge cannot be bought at any price.

You can also get new-to-you spells from friendly spellcasters for barter or gold, or seize them from the bloodied books of defeated enemy spellcasters. These are equally treasure, though you might go about getting them differently than how you seek ancient spellcasting knowledge.

Comment: Is that "Healing Word" or "Healing Worm"? I can't tell through this bloody smear...

Answer (score 13):

From [D&D Player's Basic Rules v0.2](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/basicrules), page 32 *(sidebar about a Wizard's spellbook)*:

> **Your Spellbook**
>
> The spells that you add to your spellbook as you gain levels
> reflect the arcane research you conduct on your own, as well
> as intellectual breakthroughs you have had about the nature
> of the multiverse. You might find other spells during your
> adventures. **You could discover a spell recorded on a scroll in
> an evil wizard’s chest, for example, or in a dusty tome in an
> ancient library.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Taking into consideration your post, the only way I could learn higher level rituals would be finding a scroll or something like that then?

Comment: I don't have the PHB, so I don't know if there are other ways of learning higher level Warlock rituals. Your question was about finding new spells on your adventures, which is what I answered. Note, you can also _buy_ scrolls, if you can find a seller (depends on setting, availability, etc)

Comment: @dambros yes, that is the only way.