# Gaining spells for the feat ritual caster in Adventurers League

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, dnd-adventurers-league, rituals

This is a simple enough question, I hope. I couldn't seem to find a clear answer anywhere. This is regarding an Adventurers League (AL) character.

I've taken the **Ritual Caster** feat on my character and chosen my two spells, but can I then only learn additional spells from other players?

Can I spend downtime to learn it from an NPC for example? If so, what are the costs: 2 hours and 50 gold per spell level? So a 2nd-level spell would be half a day and 100 gold?

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Related (non-AL): [How does one find new spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49236/52137) and [Can Wizards, Tome Warlocks, and those with the Ritual Caster feat use spells from each other's books?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60321/52137)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second bullet of the *[ritual caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/ritual-caster)* feat outlines the costs of the process, and those rules are unchanged for Adventurers' League. The [AL Player's Guide](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack) (on page 3 in v9.1, current at the time of this post) talks about how many hours you can spend in each downtime day copying spells.

---

The first part of the second bullet is probably the part you're stumbling on: *"If you come across a spell in written form".*

If you've picked any class *except Wizard*, the only "written form" you're going to find is spell scrolls. Sometimes you'll find them as loot during adventures, but the selection is quite limited. Fortunately, the AL Player's Guide (also on page 3 of v9.1) provides prices for buying scrolls up to fifth level<sup>1</sup> .

If you've picked Wizard, you can also copy spells from player character wizards. This uses the exact same rules as two wizards copying from each other.

<sup>1</sup><sub>There are only two ritual spells above 5th level - one Wizard (*[Instant Summons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/instant-summons)*) and one Cleric (*[Forbiddance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forbiddance)*).</sub>